# Посещение теоретической и практической частей/части

Tags: единственное-множественное-число

Посещение теоретической и практической частей обязательно.

В каком числе должно стоять слово "часть"?

У Розенталя написано, что должно быть единственное число, если перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений внутренне связаны. Подходит ли это к моему случаю? Или здесь подчеркивается наличие нескольких частей, а значит, надо употребить множественное число?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посещение **теоретической и практической (обеих)** частей обязательно.

Здесь подчеркивается наличие **двух частей, обязательных** для посещения, поэтому лучше выбрать мн. число.

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_04](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_04)

Имя существительное **ставится в форме множественного числа:**
1)      если подчеркивается **наличие нескольких предметов,** например:  академическое и массовое издания произведений классиков, широкоэкранный и обычный варианты фильма;

Answer (score 1):

Это подходит. Правда, непонятно, что такое "посещение части".

Comment: Речь идет о посещении двух частей мастер-класса.

Answer (score 1):

> Посещение теоретической и практической частей обязательно. (*Речь идет о посещении двух частей мастер-класса.*)

При таком построении предложения я бы предпочел множественное число. Ведь здесь подчёркивается наличие двух частей и требуется участие именно в обеих частях. Но не думаю, что такое выражение как "посещение части мастер-класса" является корректным. Да и само слово *посещение* может сыграть с вами злую шутку. Ведь можно сходить на одно занятие и честно сказать: "Я посетил мастер-класс". Поэтому лучше употребить слово *участие* вместо *посещение*.

А вообще-то говоря, я бы предпочел выразиться наиболее понятным образом, а именно:

**Участие как в теоретической, так и в практической части мастер-класса обязательно.**

Здесь уместно единственное число. На втором месте такой вариант (с множественным числом):

**Участие в теоретической и практической частях мастер-класса обязательно.**